# "No UHD Devices Found" in Debian 8.0.6 for Ettus USRP B200

Tags: debian, usrp

I used Debian 8.0, and no problem for UHD and system's detect USRP B200.

But Debian 8.0.6 not detect this device. And have problems under Debian 8.0 for new version USRP B200 - green (old is white). This new Ettus B200 does not work correctly with the drivers that come with the Debian's repository. The repository has the old driver 003.007. When I put UHD from source code, installed last v. 003.010, the program began to work successfully! I just started other programs - gqrx, and etc.

So, i have Debian 8.0.6 and

## uhd_find_devices

linux; GNU C++ version 4.9.2; Boost_105500; UHD_003.009.005-0-g32951af2

No UHD Devices Found

```
[ 2514.168911] usb 2-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2514.261751] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=2500, idProduct=0020
[ 2514.261757] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2514.261760] usb 2-1.6: Product: WestBridge 
[ 2514.261762] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Cypress
[ 2514.261765] usb 2-1.6: SerialNumber: 0000000004BE
[ 4419.164123] usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 4420.641402] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 4420.734450] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2500, idProduct=0020
[ 4420.734456] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4420.734459] usb 2-1.2: Product: WestBridge 
[ 4420.734462] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Cypress
[ 4420.734465] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 0000000004BE
```